# DalvikUWPCSharp.csproj' targets 'UAP,Version=v10.0.18362'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v5.0'

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I am trying to compile a C-Sharp project into a UWP app, but when I go to publish/build the app package, it comes up with this error. I tried specifying the .NET version in TargetFrameworks in both project files, but nothing happened. I also tried removing .NET, but still, no result.

DalvikUWPCSharp.csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '15.0'">
    <VisualStudioVersion>15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WapProjPath Condition="'$(WapProjPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\</WapProjPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>2f5873b5-8b81-4c5f-ab37-31ac353e4955</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <TargetFramework>UAP,Version=v10.0.18362</TargetFramework>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    <EntryPointProjectUniqueName>..\DalvikUWPCSharp\DalvikUWPCSharp.csproj</EntryPointProjectUniqueName>
    <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>WapProjTemplate3_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
    <AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA512</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Images\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <None Include="WapProjTemplate3_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DalvikUWPCSharp\DalvikUWPCSharp.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets" />
</Project>
```

WapProjTemplate3.wapproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '15.0'">
    <VisualStudioVersion>15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WapProjPath Condition="'$(WapProjPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\</WapProjPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>2f5873b5-8b81-4c5f-ab37-31ac353e4955</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <TargetFramework>UAP,Version=v10.0.18362</TargetFramework>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    <EntryPointProjectUniqueName>..\DalvikUWPCSharp\DalvikUWPCSharp.csproj</EntryPointProjectUniqueName>
    <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>WapProjTemplate3_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
    <AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA512</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Images\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <None Include="WapProjTemplate3_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DalvikUWPCSharp\DalvikUWPCSharp.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets" />
</Project>
```

Thanks,
Ayden Bottos

Comment: Hello, have you installed UWP development related dependencies for your computer? (Open the **Visual Studio Installer**, select the corresponding Visual Studio version and modify it, check **Universal Windows platform development**) and whether the 18362 Windows SDK is installed?

Comment: Yes, but thanks for asking.

Comment: So can you provide a minimal runnable demo? This helps us reproduce your problem and analyze

Comment: Thank you, but I fixed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem! All I had to do was specify .NET as a package reference and perfect! Thanks for the help, Richard Zhang!

Comment: Hello, so glad you found a solution. You can mark your answer, this will help more people who encounter the same problem.